# Is there a way to set all of the entries of a map to a value

Tags: javascript

I have an array that I want to use as the keys to my map and set each value to true.  Is there a way to do this besides using a forEach loop on my array to set each entry?  This is how I am doing it now:

```
const list = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const myMap = new Map();
list.forEach(element => myMap.set(element, true));
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can pass an array to the `Map` constructor, but the array should be 2 dimensional. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Relation_with_Array_objects)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more concise, functional, way, would be to pass a map of the list as an argument to the Map:

```
const list = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const myMap = new Map(list.map(key => [key, true]));
```

This works because `new Map` [takes an iterable of key/value pairs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Syntax). Arrays are valid iterables.

The `list.map` makes the code evaluate similarly to

```
new Map([
  [0, true],
  [1, true],
  [2, true],
  [3, true]
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array for the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) constructor.

```js
const list = [0, 1, 2, 3];
const myMap = new Map(list.map(k => [k, true]));

console.log([...myMap]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use a solution with `Map` then mind potential browser compatibility issues (like old IE). See more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Map's constructor

```
new Map(list.map(x=>[x, true]))
```

Comment: @ochi is that better?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const list = [0, 1, 2, 3];
map = new Map(list.map(index => [index, true]));
```